# (Is same case) loop return not working properly

Tags: python

https://codewars.com/kata/5dd462a573ee6d0014ce715b

> Write a function that will check if two given characters are the same case.
>
> - If either of the characters is not a letter, return `-1`
> - If both characters are the same case, return `1`
> - If both characters are letters, but not the same case, return `0`
>
> Examples
>
> `'a'` and `'g'` returns `1`
> `'A'` and `'C'` returns `1`
> `'b'` and `'G'` returns `0`
> `'B'` and `'g'` returns `0`
> `'0'` and `'?'` returns `-1`

```
char1 = 'G'
char2 = 'a'

def is_same_case(char1,char2):
    if char1.isupper() and char2.isupper or char1.islower() and char2.islower:
        return 1
    elif char1.isupper() and char2.islower or char1.islower() and char2.isupper:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1

print(is_same_case(char1,char2))
print(char1.isupper())
print(char2.isupper())
```

It returns 1 instead of 0.

Comment: what does `if char2.isupper` return? What is that trying to evaluate?

Comment: You're missing `()` on the `char2.isupper` and `char2.islower` function calls.

Comment: For what its worth, the case comparison can be simplified to `a.isupper() == b.isupper()`

Comment: @Sayse Generally yes, but that won't cover the `?` → `-1` case…

Comment: Sometimes you call the method `isupper()` sometimes you don't `isupper`. Always call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the `isalpha()` method to test cases that aren't letters, and then perform a comparison of the `isupper()` method, and convert the boolean to an integer

```py
def is_same_case(char1, char2):
    if not (char1.isalpha() and char2.isalpha()):
        return -1
    return int(char1.isupper() == char2.isupper())
```